# PHP+Erro no envio de arquivos

Tags: php, html, arquivo, post, upload

Bom dia pessoal.
Estou tentando fazer um Upload simples de vídeo em PHP.
O meu código em HTML está aqui:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Aproveite o site</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="videosUpload.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="texto">
            <input type="file" name="file">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        
        <a href=sair.php>sair</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

O meu código em PHP está aqui:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
            echo $_POST['texto'];

            //resto do código criado
        ?>
        <a href="videos.php">Voltar</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

O problema é: Quando eu não seleciono um arquivo para fazer o upload, o 'echo' mostra o valor do campo passado pelo método POST, mas se eu selecionar um arquivo de vídeo, apresenta o seguinte erro: Undefined index: texto.

Alguma solução?

Eu estou usando o UwAMP em uma máquina Windows10.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso está acontecendo porque você está tentando imprimir o valor de `$_POST['texto']` independente se ela existe algum valor ou não.

Tente isso, verifique primeiro se a variável foi iniciada:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['texto'])) {
 // Resto do código aqui...
}
```

Referência: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php

Comment: Show. Funcionou. Obrigado.